# AWS Certificate in ACM service does not get validated successfully

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I use Terraform to deploy ACM in front of my CloudFront service:

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "primary" {
  name          = var.domain_name
  comment       = "Hosted Zone for URL shortener application, managed by Terraform"
  force_destroy = true

  tags = merge(
    var.common_tags,
    {
      Name = "${var.project}-Route53-Zone",
    }
  )
}
```

```
# CloudFront supports US East (N. Virginia) region only
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "cloudfront_certificates_region"
  region = "us-east-1"
}

module "acm_cloudfront" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/acm/aws"
  version = "5.0.0"

  providers = {
    aws = aws.cloudfront_certificates_region
  }

  domain_name         = var.domain_name
  zone_id             = aws_route53_zone.primary.zone_id
  wait_for_validation = true
  validation_method   = "DNS"

  tags = merge(var.common_tags, var.acm_tags)
}
```

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "acm_validation_record" {
  for_each = {
    for dvo in module.acm_cloudfront.acm_certificate_domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      name   = dvo.resource_record_name
      record = dvo.resource_record_value
      type   = dvo.resource_record_type
    }
  }

  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = each.value.name
  records         = [each.value.record]
  ttl             = 60
  type            = each.value.type
  zone_id         = aws_route53_zone.primary.zone_id
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "acm_validation" {
  certificate_arn         = module.acm_cloudfront.acm_certificate_arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [for record in aws_route53_record.acm_validation_record : record.fqdn]
}
```

After running `terraform apply` I get this error:
`Error: waiting for ACM Certificate (arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:fffffff:certificate/fffffff) to be issued: timeout while waiting for state to become 'ISSUED' (last state: 'PENDING_VALIDATION', timeout: 1h15m0s)`

When I view the certificate in ACM:
[image]

And the corresponding route in Route53:

[image]

so why the certificate is still pending validation?

Comment: is the domain otherwise public & valid? can you resolve the record yourself? And is it really the one issued by ACM? Also, sometimes, the first validation takes a random amount of time between a minute and few hours. I had never an issue with renewals though.